# Using Simple Imputer with Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am working with the following dataset:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data

which it says that has some missing values marked with "?". I want to apply the SimpleImputer library and my code is the following:

```
file="breast_cancer"
df=pd.read_csv(file,names=['id', 'clump_thickness','unif_cell_size',
                                                         'unif_cell_shape', 'marg_adhesion', 'single_epith_cell_size',
                                                         'bare_nuclei', 'bland_chromatin', 'normal_nucleoli','mitoses','class'])
df.replace('?',np.NaN,inplace=True)
imp=SimpleImputer(missing_values="NaN")
idf=pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df))
idf.columns=df.columns
idf.index=df.index
```

so I want to replace all the ? values from all the columns with the mean, and return a new dataframe. The problem is that I got the following error:

```
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to impute a `"NaN"`, a `str`, whereas you've replaced `?` with `np.NaN`.

Instantiate `SimpleImputer` with `np.nan` and works fine:

```
df.replace('?',np.NaN,inplace=True)
imp=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.NaN)
idf=pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df))
idf.columns=df.columns
idf.index=df.index

idf['bare_nuclei'].isna().sum()
```

Output:

```
0
# No nan : Imputing successful
```

Comment: Would saving df.columns and df.index and replacing idf with df in idf=pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df)) use less memory if the dataset is very large or does pandas avoid saving df and idf separately?

Answer (score 0):

Try these things on your dataframe:

```
df.info()
df['bare_nuclei'].unique()
```

You'll notice that 'bare_nuclei' is not a numeric variable. To get any mean imputation you'll need to pass in numeric data (hence your error of not being able to convert to `dtype('float64')`.

You can convert a column to numeric data after you replace '?' with 'NaN'

```
df['bare_nuclei'] = pd.to_numeric(df['bare_nuclei'])
```